# Instance variables in Ruby; why do I have to (sometimes) specify `self`?

Tags: ruby

Why do increment_v1 and_v3 work, but increment_v2 and _v4 don't (v2 returns the correct value, but doesn't change the `@counter`, v4 fails with "NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)")

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :counter

  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def increment_v1
    @counter = counter + 1
  end

  def increment_v2
    counter = @counter + 1
  end

  def increment_v3
    @counter += 1
  end

  def increment_v4
    counter += 1
  end
end
```

I expect all of these methods to have the same outcome (increase the `@counter` value and return the increased number). It has the same error if I replace `attr_accessor` with `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`.  I feel like I may be misunderstanding something about the `attr_*` methods.

Here is what it looks like in the console:

```
2.6.3 :026 > a = MyClass.new
 => #<MyClass:0x00000000018d7240 @counter=0>
2.6.3 :027 > a.increment_v1
 => 1
2.6.3 :028 > a
 => #<MyClass:0x00000000018d7240 @counter=1>
2.6.3 :029 > a.increment_v2
 => 2
2.6.3 :030 > a
 => #<MyClass:0x00000000018d7240 @counter=1>
2.6.3 :031 > a.increment_v3
 => 2
2.6.3 :032 > a
 => #<MyClass:0x00000000018d7240 @counter=2>
2.6.3 :033 > a.increment_v4
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /home/guin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /home/guin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /home/guin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):33
        1: from (irb):23:in `increment_v4'
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

Running `a.counter += 1` from outside the class works as I expect. Do I have to specify `self.counter += 1` when I am inside the class? Why? It even works if with `self.counter = counter + 1`. What is going on?

Comment: @Max has answered your question, but another time you must use `self` as an explicit receiver is when you want to invoke the method [Object#class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-class) (e.g., `def my_class; self.class; end`). I understand that's because `class` is also the keyword for defining a class (though I'd think Ruby could easily figure out from the context which `class` was intended). I have the nagging feeling that there is a third situation where an explicit `self` is needed, but it does not come to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have shown, you can always access an attribute directly using the instance variable (`@counter`). However your issue here is relating to the getter/setter methods generated by `attr_accessor`.

The getter method does not require self *unless* you have a local variable with the same name. Setter methods are different. You *always* need to use self with setters.

For example:

```
def test_method
  # directly set instance var. this will always work
  @counter = 1  

  # define local variable with same name.
  # this does not call the setter because you don't use self
  counter = 0 

  puts counter
  # prints 0
  # The getter method is never called because you have a local variable
  # with the same name.

  puts self.counter
  # prints 1
  # you can force the getter to be called by using self
end
```

I think the idiomatic way to write your method would be:

```
def increment_v5
  self.counter += 1
end
```

However you could also write it like this:

```
def increment_v6
  self.counter = counter + 1
  #                \ calls getter
end
```

and there are many other ways to write it.

Comment: Good answer. I know it's subjective but I'd say that the idiomatic way would be `@counter += 1`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. It's not in my original question, but I've just noticed that using the `private` keyword makes `self.counter += 1` not work, with NoMethodError "private method 'counter' called". However, `self.counter = counter + 1` does work in that instance.  Is this related?

Comment: @Jen I think its the opposite, see https://content.pivotal.io/blog/private-setters-in-ruby-what-to-do